# MultivaluedSection with reorder controls don't show up if form is generated after async call

Tags: eureka-forms

I'm generating a form with a reorderable MultivaluedSection and creating the form after an asynchronous call to my backend API. When the form is displayed, the reorderable controls don't show up.  But if I make the form without an async call, then they show up fine.  I'm not sure how to make it all work right with the async call.  Any ideas?  Below is code that illustrates the behavior. If you run test() without the Dispatch delay, then it'll render correctly.  Also, as a fun Easter egg, if you display this in a navigation controller as something other than the root and start to drag to pop back to the previous, but let it go early and don't let it pop back to the root, then the reorder controls will also show up.  Any ideas how to fix this?

```
import Eureka

class TestFormViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3, execute: {
            self.test()
        })
    }

    func test() {

        self.form +++ MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: [.Reorder],
                                     header: "Section Items") { formSection in

            formSection.tag = "items"

            for i in 0...5 {

                formSection <<< LabelRow() {

                    $0.title = "Row " + String.init(describing: i)
                    $0.value = "Row " + String.init(describing: i)

                    $0.cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
                        cell.detailTextLabel?.isHidden = true
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I've tried doing a tableView.reloadData() and a reload on the section, but those don't seem to do anything productive.

Edit 2: I found a workaround by building the form in viewDidLoad before getting the data from the async call.  Then once I have the data assign the values to the correct form elements and add the reorderable rows at this point.  That seems to do the trick.  For regular TextRow or TextArea type rows, I needed to also run updateCell() on them after setting the value to get them to show up.